# Is fill row method preserving the order of the elements (SQL CLR function)?

Tags: c#, regex, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sqlclr

I have the following `C#` function:

```
[SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "FillRowForSplit")]
public static IEnumerable Split(SqlString sqlInput, SqlString sqlPattern)
{
    string[] substrings;

    if (sqlInput.IsNull || sqlPattern.IsNull)
    {
        substrings = new string[0];
    }
    else
    {
        substrings = Regex.Split(sqlInput.Value, sqlPattern.Value);
    }

    return substrings;
}

public static void FillRowForSplit(Object value, out SqlString sqlValue)
{
    sqlValue = new SqlString(value.ToString());
}
```

It is generally splitting values by regular expression. Here is the `T-SQL` definition:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [RegexSplit](@input NVARCHAR(MAX), @pattern NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE ([value] NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [Utils].[RegularExpression].[Split];
GO
```

And this is working example:

```
SELECT [value]
FROM [RegexSplit]('10527,!!10528,!!10529,!!10530,!!10526', ',!!');
```

[image]

The questions is "Can I be sure that the order of the separate elements is preserved?" or I should rewrite the `C#` function in order to match each element with index and return the index, too.

Comment: Regex.Split should preserve the order as it's traversing the string from the first character to the last.

Comment: imo, I would added the index, if order is critical. Order may be preserved in such simple case, but order of elements returned by select statement is undefined without `order by` clause. Who knows what may happen in the kitchen of sqlserver query processor, for exampe if it would be `select T.col, RS.value, row_number() over (partition by T.col1 order by T.col2) from T cross apply RegexSplit(T.col, @delimiter) order by T.col` and this in turn is subpart of the larger query. Between output of FillRow and its destination point data may be spooled, segmented, and get reordered probably.

Comment: @i-one Yes,  I have added an index in order to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the separate elements is preserved because `Regex` sequentially processes characters even if `RightToLeft` option is specified for `Regex`.